# Leer logs en un directorio en tiempo real (LogWatcher)

Tags: python

Estoy intentando hacer un logwatcher de un directorio específico usando python. El objetivo es simple, buscar unos regex en unos logs y en función de estos regex escribir en un archivo txt una entrada.

El problema viene en que tiene que ser un script que se esté ejecutando constantemente contra un directorio del que puede haber varios logs de nombres desconocidos, no un log específico, y tiene que detectar la creación de nuevos logs en dicho directorio y leerlos on the fly.

He hecho una especie de tail -f en python que lee constantemente un log específico y actúa en consecuencia, pero no sé cómo podría hacerlo para leer un directorio entero y detectar al instante, mientras está en ejecución, si existe un log nuevo en el directorio para leerlo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time, os, re
from datetime import datetime

# Regex used to match relevant loglines
error_regex = re.compile(r"ERROR:")
start_regex = re.compile(r"INFO: Service started:")

# Output file, where the matched loglines will be copied to
output_filename = os.path.normpath("log/script-log.txt")

# Function that will work as tail -f for python
def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line


logfile = open("log/service.log")
loglines = follow(logfile)
counter = 0

for line in loglines:
    if (error_regex.search(line)):
        counter += 1
        sttime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S - ')
        out_file=open(output_filename, "a")
        out_file.write(sttime + line)
        out_file.close()
    if (start_regex.search(line)):
        sttime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S - ')
        out_file=open(output_filename, "a")
        out_file.write(sttime + "SERVICE STARTED\n" + sttime + "Number of errors detected during the startup = {}\n".format(counter))
        counter = 0
        out_file.close()
```

Comment: El módulo [`watchdog`](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/index.html) puede ser útil.

Comment: @abulafia soy muy newbie con python. Cómo se podría integrar esa librería con el código que tengo hecho?